# svn command line: how can I get a file from history?

Tags: svn

I know svn can get log of history, e.g.

```
$ svn log -v -r32 http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/test/
------------------------------------------------------------------------
r32 | sally | 2003-01-13 00:43:13 -0600 (Mon, 13 Jan 2003) | 1 line
Changed paths:
   M /a.dll
...
```

But how can I get that dll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically you can always get the item by adding an "@" and the revision to the complete URL:
Example:

```
svn export http://svn.red-bean.com/repos/test/a.dll@r32  ./a.dll
```

Note that you need `export` if you want to copy this file/directory to a arbitrary filedestination. If you want to copy it into an existing working copy (usecase: revive already deleted items), you should use `copy`, to preserve Version history